# Validity of multilevel modeling to include results for multiple psychometric tests with subscales #statsnube

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, multilevel-analysis, validity

I have survey data for approx n = 1650 for multiple psychometric tests (all participants have completed all the tests), and about 12 outcome variables (from a PCA of a 52-question survey, e.g. medication adherence, health perceptions, etc.). The question is essentially *"what psychological/psychiatric traits relate to these behaviours/beliefs"*. I may decide to narrow the focus to fewer outcome variables.

Because I suspect significant interaction between these variables, **is it reasonable to perform multilevel regression on this?** This seems like a non-standard application of the analysis, and I've pretty much self-taught myself stats over the past 6 months (I have a medical degree so i have pretty limited prior knowledge), so I'm scared I'm overlooking some major reason this would be invalid...

Also, **is it valid to just run a separate analysis for each outcome variable?** They're not particularly correlated with eachother... most extreme pearson coefficients are .434 and -.305

The data are often slightly skew (e.g. in the OCIR, with a range of 0-72 and < 21 is considered non-pathological, there is an unsurprising right skew), and this seems to be more pronounced in the subscales. I spent a lot of time in my previous project finding non-parametric equivalents for things, but I'm not sure what to do here. I've attached some pictures. I've read that regressions are often "relatively robust"... not sure how much i can lean on that.
The outcome variables are all varying degrees of not normally distributed. (see below)

*Any comments/suggestions (including pointing out why what I'm doing is completely wrong, or assumptions that need testing) are hugely appreciated*

### **Additional info:**

> Looking at maybe using the Universty of Bristol's MLwiN (centre for multilevel modelling)...
> I am resigned to teaching myself R at some point (I have python basics), but I've mainly been using SPSS for analyses and GraphPad Prism for prettier graphs.
>
> we do not know if the participants have a psychiatric diagnosis, it was an online questionnaire, and that was not asked.
>
> Psychometric scales:
>
> - Obsessive–Compulsive Inventory-Revised (OCI-R)
>   6 OCIR subscales: obsessing, washing, checking, neutralising, ordering, hoarding
> - Self-regulation questionnaire (SRQ)
>   SRQ subscaless: assessing, receiving, evaluating, triggering, searching, planning, implementing
> - Hospital Anxiety and Depression scale
>   2 HADS subscales (not often used as a total score): anxiety score, depression score
> - Memory score (created by the researcher who composed the survey) (I still need to create a combined score of the two components):
>   components 1: free recall of 30 bold words from a paragraph (score out of 30)
>   component 2: working memory test score (recall an increasing number of a series of characters) (score out of 8)

[image: OCIR data - super exploratory, ignore the titles etc - my variable labels and names are switched.]
[image: scores for the washing OCIR subscale]
[image: SRQ]
[image: HADS anxiety component. the most normal data i have ever had the pleasure of beholding.]
[image: Working memory test]
[image: distribution of outcome factors. each factor is an average of the scores of the questions that loaded for that factor between 1 and 5, except for the last one, which is a single question that didn't load with any of the other factors, and is a binary question]

Turns out you can't solve all stats with ANOVAs :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like serial multiple linear regressions, removing independent variables one by one and using the change in R2 as a measure of the importance of each scale is the way to go.

It seems multilevel modelling is typically used where the levels refer to cases/units - i.e. the cases aorm mutually exclusive groups (the typical "pupils in various schools" scenario). What I wanted was a way to hierarchically evaluate the relevance of variables. What I can do using  MLR, from what i understand, is batch remove/add the subscales to evaluate their grouped relevance.

Time to properly learn pandas, i guess...

(All science leads to learning data science...)